# cv2 error while in execution Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I'm running some Python scripts in a loop (but not so fast).

example:

```
import time
import cv2
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    time.sleep(10)
```

After some minutes of execution I'm getting this error:

```
E1205 11:19:12.803174714   32302 backup_poller.cc:132]       Run client channel backup poller: {"created":"@1607177952.802346313","description":"pollset_work","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":324,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1607177952.802226759","description":"Bad file descriptor","errno":9,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.cc","file_line":954,"os_error":"Bad file descriptor","syscall":"epoll_wait"}]}
```

Does someone know what is this? I looked into Google but I didn't find any good solutions.

Comment: Code works fine for me. Maybe you should reduce the `time.sleep(10)` to `time.sleep(1)` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

after creating a VideoCapture, always test for `stream.isOpened()`. if that is False, you can't do anything to the video.

after `ret, frame = stream.read()`, always test if ret is True. if it's False, the video has ended and you need to end the loop.

I would also recommend **not** simply sleeping for ten seconds. during that time, the GUI event loop won't run (because you aren't running `waitKey`), which makes the imshow window unresponsive and your OS might decide to kill the process.

use waitKey(10000) instead. check if waitKey() waited the full interval. it may return earlier because of a key event. you could accept that or repeat waitKey with the remaining time.

a camera will produce frames in regular intervals, no matter if you read them or not. if you don't read them, they queue up. the driver will not like that and may decide to throw errors at you.

Comment: i changed as you told. but same error after 7 min running my code :(

Comment: you're quick. I edited my answer a time or two (I think). see if my advice about a longer waitKey interval helps.

Comment: I think I understand your issue a little better now. please check my updated answer at the end.

Comment: ok . i will test now and report here . thank you.

Comment: sorry. it happens again . i taked of imshow and waitkey and same error after 5 min]

Comment: you will have to read the frames as fast as they are coming from the camera. you can't throttle that. you can try setting the CAP_PROP_FPS property on the VideoCapture object to slow it down but you can't throttle it.

Comment: use this https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/15c3910f243a42dcd9d4a40fcdb24e40 you absolutely cannot throttle the stream. this will match your consumer's speed by "dropping" frames